# Case Statements, subqueries, and datediff

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

First time posting on this website so please let me know if you require any other information. This first section of code worked perfectly and resulted in correct information.

```
[Field 1] = (CASE 
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, (
                   SELECT TOP 1 convert(varchar(10),bn1.bn_date,101) 
                   **FROM BILLING_NOTES bn1**
                   **WHERE bn1.bn_invnum=inv1.i_id**
                   ORDER BY bn1.bn_id desc), @Today) >= 45
                 THEN 'N'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, (
                   SELECT TOP 1 convert(varchar(10),bn1.bn_date,101) 
                   FROM BILLING_NOTES bn1 
                   WHERE bn1.bn_invnum=inv1.i_id 
                   ORDER BY bn1.bn_id desc), @Today) IS NULL
                 THEN'N'
                 ELSE 'Y'
             END),
```

I needed to add an additional parameter and split this column into two columns. The following is not giving me correct results, in fact it is just displaying every row as 'Y' for the following two columns. Can anyone assist me with how/why the addition of extra WHERE conditions and FROM joins caused this to go haywire?

```
[Field 2] = (CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, (
                  SELECT TOP 1 convert(varchar(10), bn1.bn_date,101) 
                  **FROM BILLING_NOTES bn1**
                   ** LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoices inv1 on inv1.i_id=bn1.bn_invnum**
                    **LEFT OUTER JOIN Client_episode_fs cefs1 on **
                   ** cefs1.cefs_id=inv1.i_cefsid **
                   ** LEFT OUTER JOIN PPS_ResubmitEBHistory prh on **
                   ** prh.invnum=inv1.i_id 
                  **WHERE inv1.i_cefsid=cefs1.cefs_id AND **
                    **bn1.bn_invnum = inv1.i_id AND prh.rap=1 **
                  ORDER BY bn1.bn_id desc), @Today) >= 45
                THEN 'N'
                WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, (
                  SELECT TOP 1 convert(varchar(10), bn1.bn_date,101) 
                  FROM BILLING_NOTES bn1
                    **LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoices inv1 on inv1.i_id=bn1.bn_invnum**
                    **LEFT OUTER JOIN Client_episode_fs cefs1 on **
                    **cefs1.cefs_id=inv1.i_cefsid**
                    **LEFT OUTER JOIN PPS_ResubmitEBHistory prh on **
                   ** prh.invnum=inv1.i_id **
                 ** WHERE inv1.i_cefsid=cefs1.cefs_id**
                   ** AND bn1.bn_invnum = inv1.i_id**
                    **AND prh.rap=1** 
                  ORDER BY bn1.bn_id desc), @Today) IS NULL
                THEN 'N'
                ELSE 'Y'
             END),
```

Comment: You may get faster response if you highlight where the changes were made specifically. Reading through all that code will drive people crazy and just give up (I know I did after only a couple lines).

Comment: You were missing an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause on Field 2. I added it in my edits, just FYI.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you're doing the exact same complex query twice, just to do a datediff on the single value returned by that query? Why not run it once, store the value in a variable, and datediff the variable in your CASE statement? It would perform better and be much less error-prone.